# Calculation of the Probability of Default

Tags: credit-risk, default-probability

I am reading a book from *Tiziano Bellini* namely *IFRS 9 and CECL Credit Risk Modelling and Validation*, to understand the default probability calculation (link : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128149409000104?via%3Dihub)

Author has provided some *R* code to illustrate the *PD* calculation. The *Page-51*, says that -

```
# 1. Default flag definition and data preparation
# 1.1. Import data
oneypd<- read.csv(’chap2oneypd.csv’) [,2:45]
library(dplyr)
# 1.1.1. Data overview: data content and format
dplyr::glimpse(oneypd)
# $ id <int> 6670001, 9131199...
# $ vintage_year <int> 2005, 2006...
# $ monthly_installment <dbl> 746.70, 887.40...
# $ loan_balance <dbl> 131304.44, 115486.51...
# $ bureau_score <int> 541, 441...
# ...
# 1.1.2. Date format
library(vars)
oneypd <- dplyr::mutate_at(oneypd, vars(contains(’date’)),
funs(as.Date))
class(oneypd$origination_date)
# 1.1.3. Round arrears count fields
oneypd$max_arrears_12m<- round(oneypd$max_arrears_12m,4)
oneypd$arrears_months<- round(oneypd$arrears_months,4)

# 1.2. Default flag definition
oneypd<- dplyr::mutate(oneypd,
default_event = if_else(oneypd$arrears_event == 1 |
oneypd$term_expiry_event == 1 |
oneypd$bankrupt_event == 1, 1,0))

# 1.3. Database split in train and test samples
# Recode default event variables for more convenient use
# 0-default, 1-non-default
oneypd$default_flag<-
dplyr::if_else(oneypd$default_event == 1,0,1)
# Perform a stratified sampling: 70% train and 30% test
library(caret)
set.seed(2122)
train.index <- caret::createDataPartition(oneypd$default_event,
p = .7, list = FALSE)
train <- oneypd[ train.index,]
test <- oneypd[-train.index,]
```

Then, he created following table -

[image]

However I failed to replicate the generation of the variables starting with `woe_` i.e. `woe_cc_util` etc.

Can you please help me to create corresponding `R` codes to construct those variables? The data is available from the link - https://www.tizianobellini.com/copy-of-chapter-2-4

Really appreciate for any pointer.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see author shares hardcoded WOE information in https://www.tizianobellini.com/copy-of-data-and-code within the name of "Complementary Software Code". If you want to dig yourself in you can try several packages in R such as smbinning or Klar.